What does a byte-boundary mean in this example from Tanenbaum's book on subnetting?
To make CIDR easier to understand, let us consider an example in which a
block of 8192 IP addresses is available starting at 194.24.0.0. Suppose that Cam-
bridge University needs 2048 addresses and is assigned the addresses 194.24.0.0
through 194.24.7.255, along with mask 255.255.248.0. This is a /21 prefix. Next,
Oxford University asks for 4096 addresses. Since a block of 4096 addresses must
lie on a 4096-byte boundary, Oxford cannot be given addresses starting at
194.24.8.0. Instead, it gets 194.24.16.0 through 194.24.31.255, along with subnet
mask 255.255.240.0.
Above is an example from Tanenbaum's book, Computer Networks. I do understand in general why random subnet splitting is error-prone and how important it is to avoid overlapping, but I don't get the "4096-byte boundary". What does it mean? The first subnet address should be divisible by the number of blocks, 4096 in this case, but what does it have to do with byte boundaries?
Maybe, I'm missing something.

This two-part answer explains it all.

Remember that books often have errors, and errata exist for them. We cannot answer for the author.

@RonMaupin, okay, I see why the question is closed and that answer is terrific. That said, do you think the explanation from the book is a bit inaccurate?

I really do not have the full context. You can check the publisher web site for errata on the book. I think I get what the author was aiming at. I think I explained it better in the section of my answer about subnets of different sizes.

@RonMaupin, I have checked the errata, it's not there. I mean, the paragraph above is the full context. As in your answer, the author is trying to explain that block ranges of size N must be contiguous so the first network address should have all 0s in the host part. My question is rather about the specific "4096-byte boundary". This isn't a byte boundary, isn't it? Rather, it's a 4096-block (or address) boundary

@DonDraper A block with 4096 addresses encompasses 16 /24 ranges. Therefore, the third octet needs to be divisible by 16 and the block starting with 194.24.8.0 can't be used but 194.24.16.0/20 can. Also, 194.24.8.0/20 is not a prefix as not all host bits are zero.

The term 4096-byte boundary is a non-standard term that Tanenbaum uses. Like Ron Maupin pointed out, this could possible be a typo. I believe it is Tanenbaum's expression for /20. It is the boundary that breaks up the IPv4 address space into blocks of 4096 addresses each.
